# When you link html file to js file , do you have to add some (linking) code to js file ?

Tags: javascript, html, file, hyperlink

When you link html file to js external file , do you have to add some (linking) code to js file ? 
We have lot of explanation to link html file with js file BUT nothing is said on what to add on js file . Do you have to write something at the top of js file ? 
thanks !
(! my question is not "How to link html file to js file?" ! this question has already be answered)

Comment: This is something you could have simply tried in far less time than it took to type in the question.

Comment: You don't..  You could load HTML say via Ajax / fetch.. But Javascript knows nothing about HTML, there is no direct link.

Comment: thanks a lot all for your helpful answers !

Answer (score 2):

> When you link html file to js external file , do you have to add some (linking) code to js file ?

No.

> We have lot of explanation to link html file with js file BUT nothing is said on what to add on js file

Because there is nothing to do.

> Do you have to write something at the top of js file ?

No.